# disable automaic update for texmaker

Tags: updates, shortcut-keys, qt

I'm new to Ubuntu 15.04 and I experienced problems with Temaker, namely the keyboard shortcuts did not work after some time. However, manually installing the version compiled with Qt4 fixed the problem, but according to this [blog post](http://kebesing.blogspot.de/2014/10/broken-keyboard-shortcuts-in-texmaker.html) the problem recurs if Ubuntu automatically updates to the new version, which indeed happened. My question is if it is possible to disable automatic updates just for Texmaker to stay with the working Qt4 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a terminal window type in:

```
sudo apt-mark hold texmaker
```

which should prevent the package from getting updated in the future.  You would have to change it back to `auto` from `hold` if you want to remove it or update it in the future.